# Ext JS 3.4 lazy rendering accordions - force render of panels

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I upgraded a large app from v2 to v3.4

I have an accordion with n > 1 panels. By default the first one is expanded and all others are not. As opposed to Ext JS 2 now with Ext 3.4 the panels aren't rendered until they are expanded first. This causes multiple issues, because some code paths require the elements to be inside the DOM already.

`deferredRender` doesn't have any effect on accordions, it's just for tabs.

What I tried: Iterating over all items and calling `setActiveItem` or `setActive` but this only causes the very last panel to be actually rendered, all other are still not inside the DOM (I suppose activating an element is async, even though `animate` is `false`).

How can I tell the accordion to render all panels, even though they are collapse at first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK all components in panel with `accordion` layout are rendered immediately. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/P5Gen/3/

Notice that child components are rendered after `afterrender` event is fired on container. Actual rendering of children is made by layout, so the markup is available after `afterlayout` event is fired.

To force layout (and also to force children to render) you can call `container.doLayout(false, true)`.

If you need to invoke `doLayout` on each container with accordion layout, you can use `ComponentMgr` to do that. Example:

```
Ext.ComponentMgr.all.on('add', function(index, component){
    if (!(component instanceof Ext.Container)) {
        return;
    }
    if (component.layout !== 'accordion' && !(component.layout instanceof Ext.layout.AccordionLayout)) {
        return;
    }

    component.on('afterrender', function(sender) {
        // do layout or something else
        sender.doLayout(false, true);
    });
});
```

Comment: Your demo shows different behavior than what I'm observing, so maybe there's some other script messing with my accordions. I won't be able to check before 20th of December, but I will definitely answer/vote then.

Comment: So why do the panels in your fiddle render to the DOM right away and mine don't? Check out 15.3. on http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?70352-Upgrading-to-Ext-3

Comment: My example shows exactly opposite behaviour. Look at source code. `AccordionLayout.onLayout` invokes `ContainerLayout.renderAll` method, which, as name says, renders all components. I don't see any deferred-rendering related code, expect that related to `CardLayout` which is used in `TabPanel`. To avoid this you can set `Ext.TabPanel.prototype.deferredRender` to `false`. If you still facing that problem, try to reproduce for example on jsfiddle, so I could look at it.

Comment: I don't know what's messing with my accordions, but your code fixes most of my problems. I don't think I would have been able to reproduce this in a fiddle. thanks.